# how to combine 2 or more textures in Cycles? 2.7xxx

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing

### how to combine 2 or more textures to achieve this type of image in cycles

similar to splashing texture that as far as I remember is a texturing technique

[image]
[image]

Comment: Please elaborate a bit more about 'combine'. We can only interpret what you want to do, so answer could be inaccurate or out of the scope of what you want.

Comment: What part are you missing? combine or more than 2 textures?

Comment: Combine: there are many ways to combine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine textures using the MixRGB node(Add>Color>MixRGB in the Shader Editor):

[image]

Note that you can choose different blending types:

[image]

As you can see you can mix any textures - proceedural and image. You can mix more textures by simply adding more MixRGB nodes.

In order to mix two textures with a smooth gradient you can use a gradient texture as a factor for the mix node:

[image]

I am using a MixRB node in Multiply mode to multiply the texture coordinate vector(to scale it) by 2 to make the gradient smaller. MixRGB node is for work with color, however it does work with any numbers as well and multiply mode does what it says - multiplies the values and it even supports negative values despite the fact that colors cannot have negative values, so there is nothing wrong to use it for some math with vectors as well.

Comment: in blender 2.79?, 2.8 no work for me, not work for production is very bad and unstable, and I have neither time nor desire to be dealing with your programming errors and I'm not very interested in the development of 2.8, 2.79 covers my needs of use

Comment: @Blender There is no difference, all screenshots and steps are the same in 2.79. (Except that the "Shader Editor" is called "Node Editor".)

Comment: what I am looking for is the transition from grass land to mud and then to rock

Comment: if I understood well what you put in the nodes is a remapping of color, but I do not want remapping of color I want a smooth transition from one texture to another

Comment: That's just an example. You can change the textures to whatever you want them to be.  I'll try to update the answer and make it a bit more useful.

Comment: @BlenderBlackened, if you don't want 2.8 or have other constraints or whatever, you should at least take the time to write that in your question, don't you think?

Comment: @lemon Yes, I could, in the same way that other people who could not do it either and I always ask for 2.7 or 2.8, so it is not a topic that I want to discuss, it is quite difficult for me to get rid of the heaters here as to have to deal with one more banality

Comment: @lemon, I think that's really not a big issue here. Everything works the same in both versions in this case. I use only 2.79 for work myself, but I chose to answer assuming 2.80 just so the answer remains relevant in the future.

Comment: @BlenderBlackened I hope the updated answer is a bit better.

Comment: @MartinZ I think I know how to express it, remember how to make a splash texture? Can this be done in cycles?

Comment: @MartinZ, last comment for me on this page: just have a look at the tags below the question.

Comment: I don't understand the confusion here :D Am I misunderstanding something here? The tags on the question should be fixed they are about Cycles and Blender Render, texturing and Compositor... that's really confusing, however else than that there are no differences between 2.79 and 2.80 and the answer is good for *both*. Those are Cycles Material nodes and they are absolutely the same and function identically in both versions. If my answer is not useful because I misunderstood something, please let me know or downvote it or comment further for clarification.

Comment: @MartinZ, the point is not at all about your answer which is ok.

Comment: Martin Z's answer seems perfect, I don't understand what's Blender Blackened's problem with it, also I don't understand what the compositor tag has to do with the question

Comment: @MartinZ Too bad there's no way to give you 2 votes, thanks, it's completely correct